# lost ubuntu 14.04 default login screen

Tags: 14.04, login-screen

After trying to upgrade to gnome 3.12 unable to upgrade//
uninstalled gnome 3.12 however 
lost ubuntu 14.04 default login screen
Plz help

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a comment, but I lack the reputation...
If @Michael's answer *doesn't* work, it could be an issue with lightdm. If so, you can install gdm to get you logged in.

To Install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdm
```

To (Re)configure /  switch back to lightdm

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Comment: This worked well for me and I appreciate the additional info on how to return to lightdm (although I'm sticking with gdm for now - it's good enough and works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use tty pushing ctrl + alt + f6 that goes to tty, and then you just have to type:

```
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
     sudo -i shutdown
```

and that might work, and have installed it again.

Comment: I tried this approach first, while it didn't fix my grumpy Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) I did learn something useful and it was well worth trying, thank you.